# How to take Input from User in Raspberry Pi Terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

How to retrieve an input from the user and check what it is?

I at first tried this:

```
set /p input=Enter input:
```

This is a Windows command but I tried it
Next I tried the python one:

```
a = raw_input("Enter")
```

and

```
a = input("Enter")
```

but they didn't work too.
Do you know what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Wait, do you want Python or shell? If Python, you must run Python first

Comment: What do you mean by "they didn't work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a file greetings.sh as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a number : " number
echo "You entered $number."
if [ $number=1 ]
then
<commands>
else
<other commands>
fi
```

then set the file as executable and run it. Hey presto

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try It

Comment: sure what sort of checks do you need to run on it?

Comment: If a = 1 then "FUNCTION"

Comment: If a = 2 then "OTHER FUNCTION"